# Unable to update a table after adding a column (SQL 2008R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We just added two columns, `UserHash NVARCHAR(255)` and `UserSalt NVARCHAR(8)`, to 4 tables in our database.  For ONE of these tables, I am getting the following error about the `UserHash` column when I try to update anything on that table.

Error Message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'UserHash'.

Example `Update` statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.Users 
SET UserSalt = 'asdf', UserHash = 'SomeString' 
WHERE ID = 21237

(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

The tables were edited in SSMS, and 3 of them have had no problem.

When I select, the column is there.  Intellisense sees it.

Removing the column restores update capability.

The problem table is only exhibiting the issue on the `UserHash` column, not on the `UserSalt` column.

I've tried removing and re-adding. Same problem.
The new columns are not indexed.
I have rebuilt all the indexes on the table.

Every search I do comes up with..  "Oops.. My bad" for answers about queries and views. Have any of you SQL gurus seen this behavior?

Comment: is the column nullable or not nullable..........if not nullable, what is your default value?

Comment: Can we see the **whole** error message?

Comment: Maybe this table has an UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Column is not nullable, default is empty string.

Error:
UPDATE dbo.Users  SET UserSalt = 'asdf', UserHash = 'SomeString' WHERE ID = 21237

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'UserHash'.
<this repeated 7 more times>

Comment: And are there any triggers on the `Users` table?. Can we have the table definition?

Comment: Yes, it has an update trigger, but so do the other three mentioned.

Comment: @ZacM. Then can we see the trigger code?

Comment: Even if it is the trigger, why would ONE of the fields be ok, and the other have a problem?  Both have default values, both are NVARCHAR.  

And, all the triggers work the same adding changes to a specific set of fields to an audit table. 

For the particular table there is a problem, there have been other columns added and the update trigger has not been modified and we've had no problems.

Comment: @ZacM. "Even if it is the trigger, why would ONE of the fields be ok..."  We would need to see the trigger to say why...

Comment: @ZacM. Because maybe the trigger is pointing to some other table that doesn't have that column?, we don't know until we see the trigger, but we can tell you that if there exist that table on your column and there's nothing else going on then you wouldn't be getting that error message.

Comment: This post is going to end up with - "Oops.. My bad"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an Oops my bad, I'm suffering from legacy code from a really bad vendor..  I had to dig pretty deep to find my answer.

The "Audit" tables referenced in the triggers are field independent, however in the trigger for this particular table they use column ordinal position and some other convoluted field tracking that is not compatible with SQL 2008. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329(v=sql.105).aspx)  The audit tables and triggers for the other tables are newer, and do not have these same problems.

Now I've got to review 50+ triggers in my DB to bring them up to date.

Comment: Oops that is hard time